# Angular JS: show item only if ng-repeat has members?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have json data where a series of objects have an array "options".  Some items have items in this array and some don't, as in

```
{
  "label": "ORDERS",
  "enabled": true,
  "selected": true,
  "options": [
    {
      "label": "Edit addresses",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "label": "Cancel orders",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "label": "Uncancel orders",
      "value": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "label": "FOO",
  "enabled": true,
  "selected": false,
  "options": [

  ]
},
```

As you can see, ORDERS has options, but FOO does not.

This leads to a layout like:

[image]

I have items outside the repeater data, the Allowed header and checkbox.

I only want to show those when the options array has items.  Here's the way I laid it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/QLY9311r4nSCRUolKvLs?p=preview

I can't figure out how to hide the rows with the "Allowed" header and checkbox on the rows where there is no options array:

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. If you want to include a plunkr, that's fine. But, the code should be here for us to look over.

Comment: i tried this but doubt how much it will help u:  
<tbody ng-repeat="t in rolePrivileges"  ng-if="t.options.length !== 0">

Comment: that does seem to work.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
    <tr ng-if="t.options.length">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td align="center">Allowed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="t.options.length">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="o in t.options">
      <td></td>
      <td>{{o.label}}</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="o.selected" />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Yes! I could've sworn I'd tried that, but I guess not.

Comment: I'm not sure myself tbh, since I don't know whether javascript considers an empty array "false".  Adjusted it a little so that it should yield a true or false.

Comment: Actually, it worked in Angular 1.2 but not 1.3...  I had to use `ng-if="t.options.length !== 0"` as per @wrick17 above